# How to access notifications for AirDrop

Tags: ios, notifications, airdrop

AirDrop is somewhat flaky for me in general, but I am having a frustrating problem finding transferred files from my computer to my iPad. My iPad shows up as a possible destination when I start the transfer from my laptop, and the dialog says "Sent", but no notification pops up on my iPad to show where to open the file (a PDF).

When I turn my iPad off and on (just power up, not reboot), the file transfer is listed in Notification center, but I can't access the file or dismiss the notifications. Is there a place I can get to these files that seem to be stuck in limbo?

I am using an iPad Pro with iOS 9.3.4.

Comment: Have you checked iBooks?

Comment: I have read books there but not checked the PDFs. Will do so. Usually when it is working properly it gives me a long list of options, including iBooks...

Comment: I just AirDropped a .docx document from my MacBook Pro w/Retina with El Capitan to my iPad Pro with 9.3.4. The iPad gave me the message, "what do you want to open it with?" I selected Word. It opened it. Great. I closed Word. Then opened it again. The document was gone. It's not in "Recents." I searched my iPad for the filename. It's gone. I'm guessing, if I don't specifically save it, it doesn't save it... maybe? So if you aren't getting the "open with" alert, it would seem it may be nowhere! Whoa!

Comment: Checked iBooks and nothing there. I updated the details of my iOS version in the question...